# Алгоритм определения сортированности массива при удалении "неподходящего" элемента

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Отсортированный массив - такой массив, что его элементы расположены в неубывающем, или невозрастающем порядке, например {1, 1, 2, 4}

А массив {8, 7, 6, 222, 5, 4} будет отсортированным при удалении элемента "222"

При условии, что можно удалить не более одного элемента (т.е. 0 либо 1), какой будет максимально быстрый алгоритм определения "не полностью" отсортированного массива?

Answer (score 4):

Проход с игнорированием одного нарушения сортированности. Только если проблема в первых трех элементах, нужно рассмотреть четвертый, чтоб понять, например, что лишнее в 1-0-5 - 0 или 5 :), т.е. убывание идет или возрастание.

Быстрее `O(n)` не получится.

Comment: При размере `<4` будет `O(1)`.

Comment: @alexolut Но если вспомнить, что `O(4) = O(1)`, то утверждение остается в силе. :)

Comment: @Harry Можете представить примерное описание алгоритма прохода?

Comment: Ну, сравниваем следующий с текущим, если все то же отношение - больше или там меньше - идем дальше, нет - первое несоответствие игнорируем, по второму делаем вывод, что все плохо :) Примерно так.